# error 1006 abnormal closure when trying to access a remote hosted frontend substrate-fronend-template

Tags: substrate

error 1006 abnormal closure when trying to access a remote hosted front end.

The chain and front end are hosted together on the same machine but I am trying to access the front end remotely via VScode from a different machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ExDi.png)

You need to add port 9944 (default for chain) to the port list in VScode, this was working with the following setup:

start chain with:
./target/release/node-template --dev --tmp --rpc-cors=all

configure frontend with:
src/config/development.json

```
{
  "PROVIDER_SOCKET": "ws://127.0.0.1:9944"
}
```